# InfoPath 2010 form not getting into form library

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 form published in SharePoint. When I select "Add Document" I get the form in the browser, I fill it in and Submit it. It gives no errors but it doesn't get added to the Form Library.
Any idea on what I may be missing here?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form in InfoPath Designer and check that the Submit options are correct, i.e. pointing to the right library.

Comment: I had the library configured as "http://server/Site1/FormsLibrary/Forms", correct one should be "http://server/Site1/FormsLibrary". Thanks for the help.